# Inserting an Image to MongoDB through Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, media

I am having trouble inserting an image to MongoDB through node.js. My code is as follows:

```
var express  = require('express'),
mongoose = require('mongoose'),
fs = require('fs'),
Schema = mongoose.Schema;
app  = express(),
port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

var imagePath = '~\images\image1.png';

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');
var db = mongoose.connection;

var contentSchema = new Schema({
    _id: Schema.ObjectId,
    date: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
    user_ip: Number,
    likes: Number,
    reports: Number,
    media: {data: Buffer, contentType: String}
})

var Content = mongoose.model('content', contentSchema);

var media = new Content({
    user_ip:12345,
    likes: 1400,
    reports: 0,
    media: fs.readFileSync(imagePath)
});

media.save(function(err,media){
    if (err) return console.error(err);
    console.dir(media);
});
```

I believe what I am missing is how I am trying to upload the media, i.e. fs.readFileSync(imgpath). Is this the common approach, or is there a better one that you recommend?

Alternatively, I am open to storing the images in a folder on my server and simply adding the URL linked to the images to the JSON object in my database. This way, I do not have to worry about actually storing any media into Mongo. Does one way provide better performance than the other?

Comment: We generally recommend to our (MongoLab) users to use a blob storage (e.g. Amazon S3) to store media and add the image URL to a media metadata doc. It's a lot cheaper this way & performance should still be good.

Comment: Thanks Chris. I believe I am going to just create a file system on my Digital Ocean Server then and just store the file paths in my db.

Answer (score 0):

S3 Would be a good place to store images.. It will good performance.. We have a app that store images in file system... But it is difficult to scale... Performance is good though..

Answer (score 0):

If you are using images of format 'jpeg / png' and if they are less than 16mb, you can go with this github repo, its a module that helps saving images to mongodb easily, and without the complexity of GRIDFS, but in case if your files are greater than 16mb, you need to use GRIDFS,

This is the link for the github repo for images less than 16 mb (and also works well with react)

https://github.com/saran-surya/Mongo-Image-Converter