# How to post image in mongodb?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

Good evening people of the internet,
I am trying to post the image to Mongodb, but it doesnt work.
Edit: it looks like i am posting the image data as JSON (which i am not supposed to do) , but i dont know another way on how to do it.

Code upload middleware:

```
const path = require("path");
const multer = require("multer");

//location file
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, "uploads/");
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        let ext = path.extname(file.originalname);
        cb(null, Date.now() + ext);
    },
});

const upload = multer({
    storage: storage,
    fileFilter: function (req, file, cb) {
        if (file.mimetype == "image/png" || file.mimetype == "image/jpg") {
            cb(null, true);
        } else {
            alert("only jpg & png files");
            cb(null, false);
        }
    },
    limits: {
        fileSize: 1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 5,
    },
});
module.exports = upload;
```

code Router:

```
const router = require("express").Router();
let User = require("../model/userSchema");
const upload = require("../middleware/upload");

router.get("/", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const users = await User.find();
        res.json(users);
    } catch (Error) {
        throw new Error("error");
    }
});

router.post("/add", upload.single("image"), async (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.file);
    const user = new User({
        name: req.body.name,
        age: req.body.age,
    });
    if (req.file) {
        user.image = req.file.path;
    }
    try {
        const savedUser = await user.save();
        res.json(savedUser);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```

Code form (where the image is being uploaded):

```
fetch(`${endpoint}/User/add`, {
            method: "POST", // or 'PUT'
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(user),
        })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                console.log("Success:", data);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error("Error:", error);
            });

        //set user to blank when sendin, so client can easily add more users
        setUser("");
        setAge("");
        setImage("");
    };

    return (
        <form
            onSubmit={submitHandle}
            encType="multipart/form-data"
            method="post"
            action="/upload"
        >
            <div className="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Name birthday boy/girl</label>
                <input
                    type="text"
                    className="form-control"
                    id="exampleInputEmail1"
                    value={username}
                    onChange={changeUsername}
                    aria-describedby="emailHelp"
                    placeholder="Enter name"
                />
                <label>Enter age</label>
                <input
                    type="text"
                    value={age}
                    onChange={changeAge}
                    aria-describedby="emailHelp"
                    placeholder="Enter age"
                />
                <label>Upload photo</label>
                <input
                    type="file"
                    placeholder="upload image"
                    value={image}
                    onChange={changeImage}
                />
            </div>

            <button type="submit" className="btn btn-success">
                Create user
            </button>
        </form>
```

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62983768/1551027